# CWP: Setting up name servers and web panel at new server

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, nameserver, hostname, digital-ocean

I have installed CentOS Web Panel on my digital ocean droplet. I can access web panel using IP, and I have my domain *example.com* on name cheap.

I wanted to:

1. Access web panel using *srv.example.com*
2. And want to create *ns1.example.com* & *ns2.example.com*, so I can point sites on those records, which needs to be hosted on that server.

What I’m *confused* at:

1. How should I point my site *example.com* to server? (By using `A record` or how)
2. Should I point *srv.example.com* by adding `A record` on name cheap and create `NS records` there, and then point domain to those records?

What I’ve *tried*:

I tried to point *example.com* to server IP, and I was able to access web panel using domain, but it was accessible on main domain, and I tried to add `hostname` record as `srv.example.com` and it doesn’t work. Also, the `ns` records weren’t working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try these steps:**

1. create name records (ns1, and ns2) and point to your servers ip, (last option in **Advanced DNS** tab on namecheap)[image]
2. Follow [this guide](http://forum.centos-webpanel.com/dns/how-to-setup-dns-%28bind%29-on-server/) to setup those records on server.
3. Now add your primary domain as **User Account** on server
4. Point primary domain to newly created records (ns1 and ns2)
5. Now you can add `dns` record to point `server.example.com` to your servers ip.
6. That's it!

**PS:** usually it don't take too much time to populate dns changes, but it can take upto 48 hours so please be patient and wait for results.

Comment: ok, I'll try your guide and get back to you.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked!